# How do I fix spyder segmentation fault in Xubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, segmentation-fault, anaconda, spyder

I installed spyder using anaconda (python version 2.7), but can not start spyder. When I try to launch it through terminal, it gives the following message:

```
    $ spyder
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am using xubuntu 18.04, anaconda 1.8.7,spyder 3.2.8 . How can I fix this?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Running `conda install pyopengl` in a terminal (xterm, konsole, etc) should fix the problem.

Comment: I'm being tangential here and I apologize, but I see you're a new user and perhaps you're starting wth Python - please, please learn with Python 3.6. Don't make the mistake of using 2.7. It is old, outdated, and it's kept alive because old code still exists that will only painfully be updated to 3.x. But you're starting fresh. Do the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
conda install pyopengl
```

Fixed the problem for me. Let me know it this works.